# Python, Combining lists within a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, addition

Is it possible to combine lists in a dict to a new key?
For example, i have a dict setup

```
    ListDict = {
    'loopone': ['oneone', 'onetwo', 'onethree'],
    'looptwo': ['twoone', 'twotwo', 'twothree'],
    'loopthree': ['threeone', 'threetwo', 'threethree']}
```

I want a new key called 'loopfour' which contains the lists from 'loopone', 'looptwo', and 'loopthree'

So its list would look like

```
    ['oneone', 'onetwo', 'onethree', 'twoone', 'twotwo', 'twothree', 'threeone', 'threetwo', 'threethree']
```

and can be called using ListDict['four'] and return the combined list

Comment: `ListDict['loopfour'] = [el for l in ListDict.values() for el in l]`.

Comment: Lists are mutable.  How did you want to handle cases where the values in the list change?

Answer (score 2):

Just use two `for` clauses in a list comprehension. Note however, dictionaries are not ordered so the resulting list can come out in a different order than they were originally put in the dictionary:

```
>>> ListDict['loopfour'] = [x for y in ListDict.values() for x in y]
>>> ListDict['loopfour']
['oneone', 'onetwo', 'onethree', 'twoone', 'twotwo', 'twothree', 'threeone', 'threetwo', 'threethree']
```

If you want it ordered then:

```
>>> ListDict['loopfour'] = [x for k in ['loopone', 'looptwo', 'loopthree'] for x in ListDict[k]]
>>> ListDict['loopfour']
['oneone', 'onetwo', 'onethree', 'twoone', 'twotwo', 'twothree', 'threeone', 'threetwo', 'threethree']
```

Comment: Ah, that's just an extension. But this is much simpler than my clunky solution. However, this assumes python3.6 where dicts are ordered.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ since i didn't get a chance to comment on your solution, don't use `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y`, this is already implemented as `sum`. But the problem with that is that `+` is inefficient with lists. Don't flatten lists like this, it is an anti-pattern. Indeed, you aleady had `chain`, so all you needed was `chain.from_iterable(d.values())`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga don't you need a `*` or `.from_iterable()` for that to work?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you. It worked with AChampion's `*` modification. I've undeleted it for posterity, but I think this is a good solution too.

Comment: @AChampion yes, of course. `chain.from_iterable` is the best way

Comment: Anyway, I *suspect* that the OP really just wants a list-of-lists. That would take care of the ordering, and this seems to be a simple enumeration of some kind...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ minor point, it should be `chain.from_iterable(d.values())`, at least, it will be a tiny-bit more efficient than `chain(*d.values())` because it avoids the argument unpacking, but that isn't a really big deal unless there is a huge number of arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much! I went with this technique as itertools.chain.from_iterable did not order them. Not sure why thats considered the best way, Maybe it takes up less resources or does it faster? idk

Comment: `itertools.chain.from_iterable(iterable)` is considered preferable to if `itertools.chain(*iterable)`, not necessarily to your problem, as your require a specific order which `dict`s don't guarantee. Note: in CPython 3.6 dicts are ordered but it is an implementation detail and shouldn't be relied upon.